# Hacer sinónimos las etiquetas "css" y "css3"

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Creo que las etiquetas [css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) y [css3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) deberían ser sinónimos. CSS3 añade nuevas propiedades pero no se elimina nada, por lo que convive perfectamente con la versión anterior. Tampoco se especifica que versión de CSS estamos usando como sí lo hacemos con HTML por medio del `DOCTYPE`.

Cuando apareció CSS3 y se empezaron a usar algunas de sus propiedades cambió un poco la forma en que veíamos la maquetación y a esas técnicas (animaciones, flexbox, múltiples fondos, bordes redondeados, etc.) se las denominaba como CSS3.

Creo que a día de hoy todas estas técnicas y propiedades están perfectamente integradas en el flujo normal del trabajo de maquetación y yo al menos cuando hablo de CSS incluyo todas las propiedades de CSS3 soportadas por la mayoría de navegadores.

Pues lo dicho, yo voto por hacer que estas dos etiquetas sean sinónimos. ¿Qué pensáis?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Quiero añadir algo a este tema ya que veo que algunos preguntan que pasará cuando llegue CSS4. En realidad CSS4 no existe como tal (de hecho ni siquiera CSS3) ya que ahora la especificación CSS está dividida en módulos y cada uno tiene su propia versión y; mientras que los selectores en los que se está trabajando están en la version 4, las variables están en la versión 1, por poner un ejemplo. Seguramente nunca tengamos que crear una etiqueta [css4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) sino una etiqueta por cada módulo de CSS o al menos los más representativos.

Así que a partir de ahora no habrá versiones de CSS en todo su conjunto, y como tampoco podemos elegir que versión de CSS o de módulo usamos ya que se aplican las propiedades que soporte el navegador creo que no tiene sentido seguir hablando de CSS3 como algo diferente a CSS.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. A estas alturas no tiene mucho sentido hablar de CSS2 o CSS3. CSS en general los engloba a todos de forma más simple, creo que nos facilitará el uso de estas etiquetas.

Comment: sería interesante leer el debate que hubo en SO en 2014: [Can we please make \[css3\] a synonym of \[css\]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266926/1983854). Se decidió __no__ hacerlo, básicamente con el argumento de que _There are major changes between CSS/CSS2 and CSS3. And sometimes you want to specify that your problem is related to these new features, as media queries, animations, etc. It's good to know that the question is not simply related to CSS._. Los expertos en el tema seguro que encontráis un criterio para decidir si conviene o no.

Comment: @fedorqui. No había visto esa discusión pero es bastante vieja ya. Por eso digo "a día de hoy", quizá tuvo su lógica diferenciar hace tiempo pero creo que ya no.

Comment: @fedorqui Como dice en esa respuesta, es mejor no hacerlo, porque el día que venga CSS4, las preguntas estarán fusionadas y no se puede desfusionar.

Comment: No veo problema en eso. Si algún día tenemos [css4] se podría crear la etiqueta específica y [css] seria para todo lo demás, igual que ahora con [css] y [css3] ¿Para que íbamos a querer separar las etiquetas otra vez? No le veo el sentido

Comment: CSS3 lleva ya rondando unos años, creo a estas alturas hablar de CSS a secas sería lo más adecuado.

Comment: También tenemos esta otra discusión en SO: [When is the `[css3]` tag appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299916/when-is-the-css3-tag-appropriate) También es un poco vieja y curiosamente, ya que en la otra discusión el resultado es distinto, un usuario que opina como yo (más o menos) tiene una respuesta con bastantes votos

Comment: Es totalmente correcto lo que estás diciendo. A nivel formal, todo es `CSS`, sin versiones, y agradezco que hayas puesto esa aclaración... Aunque, la verdad, me gusta la idea de que coexistan ambas etiquetas, por un tema de organización, y poder filtrar algunas preguntas... Sin embargo, por más que esté a favor de la propuesta de organizarlo mejor, pero en contra de la generación del sinónimo, creo que estaría bueno que publiques una respuesta a favor del sinónimo, para que se pueda ver reflejada la opinión de cada usuario en votos.

Answer (score 7):

Hola perdón si sueno aguafiestas, pero a mi entendimiento hay cambios substanciales entre las versiones de css y de lo que más podría yo destacar es que en el moderno css3 aún no se terminan de implementar las funcionalidades de accesibilidad mediante css3 en todos los navegadores, y esperemos se hagan ponto, pues para el caso de css2 se ha solicitado por años mejorar el soporte de hojas de estilos aurales en firefox y safari era el único que permitía en cierta medida esto hasta que quitaron la funcionalidad por problemas legales.
En concreto, css no es solamente los módulos comunes en donde casi no se presentan cambios, normalmente las especificaciones tienen varias addendas, por ejemplo en css3 hay incluso funcionalidad orientada a ruby que podría desaparecer cuando salga css4.

Al respecto [aquí](http://lab.dotjay.com/notes/css/aural-speech/) tienen por ejemplo una comparativa en el tema de las hojas de estilo aurales.

Comment: Puede que tengas razón, no domino el tema de las propiedades de sonido en CSS. En las preguntas sobre CSS que hay en SOes  no he visto ninguna que trate temas tan específicos (corregidme si me equivoco) y siempre se podrían crear etiquetas para cosas así como ya existe, por ejemplo, [tag:flexbox] o [tag:css-transform]

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver CSS3 con Ruby?

Comment: Estoy releyendo esta respuesta y sigo sin entender en que beneficia tener las etiquetas [tag:css] y [tag:css3] separadas. Cuando uno trabaja con hojas de estilo no puede discriminar por versión, depende del navegador decidir qué propiedades se soportan y cuales no.

Answer (score 2):

En la guía de uso de [css3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) dice "La tercera edition de CSS..." lo cual es incorrecto.

De acuerdo a https://www.w3.org/TR/css-2017/#css-levels CSS no tiene versiones en el sentido tradicional, la numeración se refiere a niveles donde cada nivel alto soporta todas las funciones/características de los niveles abajo de este.

A continuación la cita textual

> 2.1. CSS Levels
>
> Cascading Style Sheets does not have versions in the traditional sense; instead it has levels. Each level of CSS builds
>   on the previous, refining definitions and adding features. The feature
>   set of each higher level is a superset of any lower level, and the
>   behavior allowed for a given feature in a higher level is a subset of
>   that allowed in the lower levels. A user agent conforming to a higher
>   level of CSS is thus also conformant to all lower levels.

Más adelante indica que no habrá CSS4.

Mas que hacer sinónimo una etiqueta de la otra propongo que se clarifiquen las guías de [css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) y [css3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) de tal forma que sean coherentes con la documentación oficial siendo [css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) la más general y usar [css3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) para preguntas específicas con las características soportadas por CSS nivel 3.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Entonces en [tag:css3] agregaríamos algo como "*siempre se debe usar junto a la etiqueta [tag:css]*"... Además, aclarar la wiki de la etiqueta no interfiere en la propuesta de sinónimo, por lo que se podría editar la wiki ahora, mientras esperamos a ver la solución de este tema.

Comment: @Mariano Creo que no voy a crear una respuesta para defender el sinónimo de momento, esta respuesta de Rubén quizá sea una mejor solución.

Comment: @Mariano Mas que algo tan tajante como "siempre", yo diría "Se recomienda..." ya que hay un límite de 5 etiquetas por pregunta

Comment: @Rubén el problema es que así, tendríamos una pregunta de CSS, que no estaría etiquetada como tal. Creo que si hay otras 4 etiquetas más importantes que [tag:Css], mejor que se use [tag:Css] en vez de [tag:CSS3]

Comment: En tal caso no sería usar junto sino recomendar preferir el uso d CSS por ser más general en tales casos de requerir otras 4 etiquetas.