# Fusionar python-3.x con python (otra vez)

Tags: discusión, estado-rechazado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hace año y medio [@Chema Cortés propuso fusionar las etiquetas `python-3.x` y `python`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/518/74). En este tiempo, han ocurrido varias cosas:

- Casi todos los proyectos de Open Stack ya están portados a Python 3.5 http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-dev/2016-June/097930.html https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Python3#Python_3_Status_of_OpenStack_projects
- Salió Ubuntu 17.10 con Python 3.6 por defecto, y Python 2 ni siquiera está instalado por defecto https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop
- Varios proyectos lanzaron versiones que ya solo soportan Python 3 http://www.python3statement.org/ incluyendo Django 2.0 beta 1 https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2017/oct/16/django-20-beta-1-released/ (versión final en diciembre)
- Microsoft detectó que Python 3 había sobrepasado a Python 2 en número de proyectos soportados https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/03/08/python-3-is-winning/
- Donald Stufft, la persona que mantiene PyPI, anunció que se había sobrepasado el 20 % de descargas de Python 3 https://twitter.com/dstufft/status/917705116442128384
- Salió pip 9.0 con soporte para discriminar versiones soportadas de Python a la hora de instalar https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#release-notes
- Salió la encuesta de desarrolladores Python de JetBrains, y Python 3 ya es usado por un 40 % de desarrolladores https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/python-developers-survey-2016/

[image: Uso de Python 3 según JetBrains]

Así que me permito volver a solicitar este cambio, porque en 2020 Python 2 <del>se va a extinguir</del> *ya no tendrá soporte oficial* y creo que es hora de mandar un mensaje muy fuerte de que **Python es Python 3, y Python 2 es *legacy***. Citando de la propuesta original:

> Propongo que la etiqueta `python` sea la etiqueta "mainstream" de
>   python, asociada a la versión 3.x, y dejar `python-2.7` para preguntas
>   relacionadas con versiones anteriores de python. Con ello, la etiqueta
>   `python-3.x` desaparecería, cuyas preguntas habría que asociarles la
>   etiqueta python en el caso de que no la tuvieran.

Comment: Con esas estadísticas podemos decir que el uso de python 2 todavía es suficientemente importante y hay que tenerlo en cuenta. Python 3 existe desde hace bastantes años como para haber desplazado totalmente a python 2 y sin embargo no lo ha hecho. No sé que ocurirá en 2020 pero a día de hoy sigue vivo.

Comment: Creo que me he expresado mal, así que he editado una frase que podía dar a entender que creo que Python 2 va a desparecer. **Python 2 no va a desaparecer**. Pero en 2020 será el Windows XP del mundo Python.

Comment: Tal y como digo en [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2894/83), me parece que se están mezclando los hechos con las voluntades. Hacia 2020 podría tener sentido lo que se comenta, pero es que la misma pregunta nos está dando datos de que actualmente ambas versiones se usan por igual. ¿Qué gana el sitio perdiendo la capacidad de filtrar preguntas específicas de Python 3? Porque no olvidemos que [la finalidad de las etiquetas es categorizar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @fedorqui. La idea no es usar las etiquetas para promover una versión de Python en particular. Eso se puede hacer con las respuestas y/o comentarios. Y, ¿qué pasará cuando salga una versión 4 de Python? ¿Tendremos entonces que crear la etiqueta `python-3.x` nuevamente y reetiquetar todas las preguntas? Mejor es seguir la convención establecida que aplica a todos los lenguajes de programación: se usa siempre la etiqueta sin versión para indicar el lenguaje. Y solo si la pregunta es específica a una versión en particular, entonces se *añade* la etiqueta versionada.

Comment: Agrego el enlace siguiente del meta en inglés que habla en cuanto a cómo etiquetar las preguntas. Sé que no necesariamente seguimos todas las mismas reglas del sitio en inglés, pero vale la pena beneficiarse de la experiencia de aquel sitio. E interesantemente, el ejemplo que se usa en la respuesta usa a Python como ejemplo: [Should I not use the generic tag if my solution is limited to a specific version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version)

Comment: El argumento de Python 4 es bueno. Voy a darle una pensada, gracias @sstan.

Comment: En esta pregunta se pide *Propongo que la etiqueta python sea la etiqueta "mainstream" de python, asociada a la versión 3.x, y dejar python-2.7 para preguntas relacionadas con versiones anteriores de python.* En la etiqueta [tag:python] se lee : *"Usa la etiqueta python para todas las preguntas que hagas sobre Python. Sin especificar nada más, se presupone que usas la versión más reciente de python."* Es decir, en este sitio ya se supone que se usa python 3 si no se dice lo contrario. Python ya está asociado a python 3 por la descripción de la etiqueta. Lo que se pide ya está hecho.

Comment: @sstan buen ejemplo este de un hipotético Python 4.

Comment: Esto es básicamente la [misma conversación que ya tuvimos con CSS y CSS3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2824/250), pero en este caso con Python y Python 3.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Pero son casos muy diferentes, en css no decidimos voluntariamente que versión usar, depende de los navegadores que se soporten ciertas propiedades o no. Tampoco tenemos una etiqueta [css2.1], solo css y css3. Ni hay problemas de compatibilidad entre versiones. No los veo comparables.

Comment: @blonfu Tienes razón. Pero ten en cuenta que aunque en CSS no decidimos voluntariamente que versión usar, tampoco decidimos que navegador usa el cliente y como bien dices hay navegadores que no soportan algunas propiedades CSS3 (al igual que habrá navegadores que no soporten características de CSS4 cuando salga) y al desarrollador le puede interesar una solución sin la última versión. Y sí, el caso de CSS es diferente, pero creo que la idea de fondo es la misma o muy parecida. A ver qué dice la comunidad.

Comment: Tampoco convenció mucho mi idea de fusionar las etiquetas de css xD, aunque está la cosa empatada. En esta de python  se empezó con mucho consenso para fusionar y van cambiando las tornas.

Comment: Sin duda el argumento mas claro es el último,  y debería leerse que solo el 40 % de los desarrolladores usan Python 3, y como todos sabrán eso responde principalmente a desarrolladores nuevos,  me atrevo a inferir que un gran porcentaje de las aplicaciones corren en Python 2, y no Python 3, y sí, pasara un buen tiempo hasta que me obliguen a actualizar mi código a Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Mejor no.

Aunque me apetece mucho empujar a los usuarios a que se pasen a Python 3, o marcar de alguna forma que la comunidad en su conjunto quiere dejar atrás Python 2, y a pesar de que ya hay indicios de que hemos pasado el punto de inflexión y que la migración está ocurriendo, *las etiquetas de Stack Overflow probablemente no son la mejor herramienta*. Ha habido dos motivos que me han convencido:

- [Este comentario de @sstan](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2890/fusionar-python-3-x-con-python-otra-vez#comment9903_2890):

> ¿qué pasará cuando salga una versión 4 de Python? ¿Tendremos entonces
>   que crear la etiqueta python-3.x nuevamente y reetiquetar todas las
>   preguntas?

No había caído en ese potencial problema de compatibilidad hacia atrás, y creo que es importante. Como sigue @sstan:

> Mejor es seguir la convención establecida que aplica a
>   todos los lenguajes de programación: se usa siempre la etiqueta sin
>   versión para indicar el lenguaje. Y solo si la pregunta es específica
>   a una versión en particular, entonces se añade la etiqueta versionada.

- [Este recordatorio de @Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2890/fusionar-python-3-x-con-python-otra-vez#comment9906_2890):

> En esta pregunta se pide *Propongo que la etiqueta python sea la
>   etiqueta "mainstream" de python, asociada a la versión 3.x, y dejar
>   python-2.7 para preguntas relacionadas con versiones anteriores de
>   python*. En la etiqueta python se lee : *"Usa la etiqueta python para
>   todas las preguntas que hagas sobre Python. Sin especificar nada más,
>   se presupone que usas la versión más reciente de python."* Es decir, en
>   este sitio ya se supone que se usa python 3 si no se dice lo
>   contrario. Python ya está asociado a python 3 por la descripción de la
>   etiqueta. Lo que se pide ya está hecho.

Faltaba alguien que leyese la descripción de la etiqueta :)

¡Gracias a los que apoyaron la propuesta y también a los que la respondieron con argumentos sólidos!

Answer (score 10):

#### No estoy de acuerdo

Hay muchos conceptos de Python que son independientes de versiones. Por otro lado, hay conceptos que sí dependen de si estás en Python 2 (2.7 generalmente) o Python 3 (3.5 normalmente).

Si hiciéramos esta unión de etiquetas sería imposible distinguir estos últimos casos, que son muchos.

Creo interesante el repaso del estado de Python que haces en la pregunta, pero sin embargo no se tiene en cuenta cómo se está usando actualmente en este sitio.

- [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tiene 1706 preguntas
- [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tiene 486 preguntas
- [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) tiene 283 preguntas

Es decir, esta *supremacía* de Python 3.x sobre un Python 2.x moribundo no se corresponden con la realidad de este sitio. Para más datos, veamos una [gráfica sobre su uso](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison#graph):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Generalmente las preguntas de Python no tienen demasiadas etiquetas, por lo que añadir [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) seguido de [python-n.m](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-n.m) no debería ser nada complicado y sería de más ayuda que imposibilitar la búsqueda de cosas referidas a Python que son específicas de la versión 3.

Comment: Precisamente en los gráficos me estás dando la razón: hay más preguntas de Python 3 que de Python 2, y las estadísticas de la etiqueta `python` no son representativas porque simplemente no sabemos a qué versión se refiere. Mi propuesta va en la línea precisamente de eliminar esa ambigüedad, y dejar claro que una etiqueta es para Python 3 (por defecto) y la otra para Python 2.

Comment: @astrojuanlu no estoy de acuerdo. Puede que muchas de las preguntas sean puramente de Python, sin importar versión, igual que puede que haya muchas que sean específicas de Python 3. El gráfico te daría la razón si se viera que Python-2 es prácticamente inexistente, mientras que actualmente tiene más de la mitad de preguntas que Python-3.

Comment: No he dicho en ningún momento que Python 2 esté moribundo o sea inexistente. De hecho ahora las descargas en PyPI de Python 2 son del 80 %, por tanto está lejos de estar muerto. Pero este es un sitio de aprendizaje, y de nuevo la propuesta tiene que ver con mandar un mensaje y ser pedagógicos. En 2017 no tiene ningún sentido empezar a programar en un lenguaje que es End Of Life en 2020.

Comment: Mi experiencia también es que Python 2.7 genera más problemas que soluciones a cualquier principiante. Además, fallos por compatibilidad (legacy) es mejor identificarlos en el orden correcto: si una pregunta aparece Python 2 debería ser etiquetada explicitamente ya que dejará de tener soporte y solo ocasionará confusión en muy corto plazo (¡2 años!)

Comment: @astrojuanlu estoy de acuerdo que es bueno apostar por la pedagogía, es una idea que comparto. Sin embargo, antes que la pedagogía está la realidad y no es nuestra función cambiarla. Muchos programadores es que están trabajando con proyectos que están incluso en Python 2.6. Si en un par de años el uso cae dramáticamente y vemos que Python 3.5 se lleva un 90% del pastel, adelante. Ahora es precipitado hacerlo. La única manera de demostrar la necesidad de esto es ser consistentes etiquetando y mostrar números.

Comment: @FZNB dos años es un mundo en este sitio. Hace dos años esto ni existía. Que esté EOL no quiere decir nada para nosotros, también Spring 2.5 está legacy y EOL desde hace tiempo y en [SO] existe la etiqueta `spring-2`. Hagamos las cosas cuando son necesarias y en función de necesidades reales, no en función de nuestras apetencias.

Comment: En este caso la propuesta de @astrojuanlu no viene por una apetencia, sino como una forma de pedagogía (como bien dices). La comunidad en pleno apuesta por python 3.x para cualquier persona o proyecto que empieza.

Comment: @mydaemon SO.es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no un grupo de presión ni un blog como para tomar posicion sobre cosas así. Podemos apostar individualmente por lo que queramos, pero no es nuestra función decidir cómo debe programar la gente.

Comment: Tu respuesta supone que el visitante promedio es capaz de distinguir una versión de otra. La experiencia señala lo contrario.

Answer (score 2):

> Python 2 se va a extinguir y creo que es hora de mandar un mensaje muy fuerte de que Python es Python 3, y Python 2 es legacy

Resume bastante bien por qué es una buena idea fusionarlo.

Comment: Resume bastante bien por qué es una buena idea usar Python 3 en vez de Python 2. Pero no por qué es buena idea empeorar la categorización de las preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo incluso diría python-2.x en lugar de python-2.7, pero la propuesta me parece bien fundamentada.

Comment: Hay cosas que están en Python 2.7 pero no en Python 2.6, por ejemplo los DefaultDicts.

Comment: y eso hace que se salga de una etiqueta 2.x?

Comment: Es un ejemplo, como dije. Hay muchas cosas más: [What’s New in Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html)

Comment: Tengo claros los cambios entre las versiones desde Python 2.3, que es cuando yo empecé a usarlo. Sigo sin ver qué diferencia *fundamental* aporta el hecho de que se use python 2.7 o python 2.6 para que evite el uso de una etiqueta genérica. Siguiendo tu misma argumentación, creamos tags python-2.5, python-2.6 y python-2.7?

Comment: Las etiquetas surgen en base a necesidades de compartimentar la informacíon. Si hubiera suficientes preguntas centradas en funcionalidades de Python 2.5, sí que sería razonable crearla. Como no es el caso a día de hoy, no la tenemos. Las etiquetas deben adaptarse a la realidad y ayudar a buscar los recursos.

Answer (score -1):

Me parece muy bien fundamentado y necesario para evitar confusiones.

Comment: ¿Qué confusiones?