# ¿Queremos descripciones de etiquetas dependientes del tiempo?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

[La descripción de la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) contiene el siguiente texto:

> Usa la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) para todas las preguntas que hagas sobre
>   Python. Sin especificar nada más, se presupone que usas la versión más
>   reciente de python.

Esto es una descripción dependiente del tiempo. En el momento de escribir esta pregunta significa que utilizas 3.7.1. O quizás signifique que usas 3.x.

En cualquier caso, si apareciese un Python 4.0 que fuese incompatible con 3.x (igual que 3.x es incompatible con 2.x) nos podemos encontrar con respuestas que eran válidas cuando se escribieron y ya no lo son.

Si quieres respuestas para 3.x y no quieres para 2.0 lo lógico es utilizar las dos etiquetas : [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) y [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), tal y como ya se dice en la descripción de la etiqueta.

Ese texto es bienintencionado. La idea es indicar que Python 2.x debe ser abandonado como obsoleto y que es mejor pasarse a 3.x . Pero tal y como está escrita presenta el problema mencionado.

Si la situación de un 4.0 incompatible aconteciese :

- ¿Querríamos borrar las respuestas para 3.x que no funcionan en 4.0? - Mucho trabajo.
- ¿Querríamos dejarlas pero no permitir respuestas de 3.x en nuevas preguntas? - Reglas cambiantes pese a que la descripción de la etiqueta no ha cambiado.
- ¿Querríamos seguir permitiendo respuestas de 3.x en preguntas solo con [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) pese a ser contrarias al que sería entonces el significado de la etiqueta? - No respetar la descripción de las etiquetas.

Comment: Esto es un tema interesante. En el sitio en inglés te dirían que la persona que pregunta/responde es responsable de mantener su pregunta/respuesta actualizada y correcta... aunque eso me parece un poco injusto (especialmente cuando hay usuarios que tienen miles de publicaciones).

Comment: Lo enfocaría desde otro ángulo: en lugar de centrarme en las respuestas, me centraría en las preguntas. Ésta es una situación asociada a una etiqueta, las etiquetas van con las preguntas, entonces sería el usuario que pregunta el responsable de añadir la etiqueta de versión correspondiente (o la comunidad, que tiene ese poder).

Answer (score 8):

Creo que las wikis de etiqueta son unas espléndidas herramientas para difundir conocimiento y estandarizar el uso en el sitio, pero no sé hasta qué punto se leen por parte de los nuevos usuarios. Además, considero que proponer una edición es muy "barato", demasiado quizás, y su influencia es demasiado grande.

Me explico:

La frase que comentas [se añadió el mayo de 2016](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6204) por parte de un usuario que, a día de hoy, está entre [los cinco con mayor puntuación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) de la etiqueta Python. Esto es, sabe de lo que habla. Ahora bien, su visión sobre el tema fíjate que determina todo el uso de una etiqueta por parte de una comunidad y crea [una especie de jurisprudencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2897/83). Y no es una etiqueta menor, sino una de las diez más utilizadas<sup>1</sup>. Ojo, no juzgo la persona, faltaría más, sino la potencia de lo que una sugerencia de edición puede provocar.

Por tanto, opino que estas orientaciones de uso sería bueno que se consensuaran algo más: utilizando un chat específico entre los expertos, creando una pregunta Meta como este caso, etc.

En este caso específico, yo considero que esta orientación de uso no ayuda y, como bien dices, puede tener un efecto nocivo porque de golpe y porrazo la version Python 4 hará obsoleto el uso actual. Ya hemos visto en [Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83) que parece que hay consenso en usar siempre [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) para todo lo relacionado con Python<sup>2</sup>. Demos un paso más y usemos solamente una etiqueta específica cuando ello sea necesario: hay muchos casos en el que la pregunta se puede solucionar sin entrar en el detalle de si es en Python 2.7 o Python 3.5+. O incluso puede ser útil que las respuestas ofrezcan las dos opciones.

Para seguir con la mirada al futuro, creo que siempre es bueno mirar qué ha hecho Stack Overflow en inglés, que con sus diez años de experiencia siempre aporta una visión que conviene mirar. En su caso, [la descripción de la etiqueta](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) no menciona esta parte.

Resumiendo:

- miremos qué hace SO y tomemos su posición por defecto y actualicémosla tras buscar consenso.
- en este caso particular, voto por eliminar esta referencia.

Tras unos días:

He sugerido [un cambio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/130306) para eliminar la frase *Sin especificar nada más, se presupone que usas la versión más reciente de python* de la descripción de la etiqueta, pues esta respuesta tiene reputación 5 (+5/-0) y la pregunta 4 (+5/-1), por lo que entiendo que hay práctica unanimidad en descartar esta descripción.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>qué fuerte que [la primera sea PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags) :D</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Y cada día me encuentro dos o tres nuevas [con Python 3 y sin Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python).</sub>