# ¿Podría modificarse la sugerencia de etiquetas al formular una pregunta para que *no* aparezca [python-3.x]?

Tags: característica-nueva, interfaz-de-usuario, formulado-de-preguntas

Llevo tiempo intrigado al ver que tantas y tantas preguntas se formulan en este sitio utilizando solamente la etiqueta [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). Ha sido motivo de distintas peticiones del tipo  [Añadamos [python] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83) o  [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta [python*]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83).

Y también ha generado debate en torno a si habría que fusionarlas (la última, [Fusión etiquetas Python (y van 3)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4797/83)).

Pues bien, iba ahora a [formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) en el sitio principal cuando he visto que la sugerencia de etiquetas se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir:

> p. ej. (array python-3.x sql-server)

Creo que la sugerencia de etiquetas está bien que esté, pero esta rema en el sentido contrario al que quiere la comunidad. Y entiendo que sea normal que un usuario nuevo (o veterano) lo vea como lógico y vinculante, de ahí que añadan rápidamente [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) y allí lo dejen.

Por ello, **¿podría modificarse la sugerencia de etiquetas al formular una pregunta para que *no* aparezca python-3.x?** Y, si eso, que aparezca sino [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) o alguna otra.

Y, de paso, hacer lo mismo con [sql-server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) pues veo que [muchísimas preguntas apenas usan esta etiqueta, sin la correspondiente [tag:sql]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+-sql).

Comment: Pues...a priori me parece que no podemos cambiarlo. Haciendo una pequeña investigación, esa cadena está en traducir.win, pero para los tags utiliza un placeholder `$TagExamples$` que entiendo que es alguna variable interna. Tal vez @g3rv4 nos pueda dar luz sobre el particular

Comment: @Pikoh se me olvidé comentarlo en la pregunta, disculpa: miré en traducir.win y al no ver la cadena allí vine a comentarlo aquí

Comment: De hecho, yo tenía la idea de que esos tags se obtenian de los mas populares. Pero viendo los que salen, parece no ser asi

Comment: En cuanto a traducir, yo entiendo que la cadena es una de estas 2: [esta](https://es.traducir.win/strings/13575) o [esta](https://es.traducir.win/strings/12282)

Comment: Ahora mismo me sale nodejs, android-studio y angular. Leí [How are “Suggested Tags” chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907/209901) de Meta.SE pero no me queda claro cómo se eligen cuando aún no se ha escrito nada. En cada SOxx salen unas diferentes.

Comment: Perdón por reabrir el hilo. Veo que se sigue usando la etiqueta [python-3.x] en solitario. Ahora que [python-2.7] ya no es versión mantenida oficialmente, creo que se podría volver a plantear la fusión de etiquetas.Y que se quede [python-2.7] para preguntas relativas a la versión antigua de python.

Comment: @ChemaCortes claramente en desacuerdo. Se ha debatido muchas veces, [véase esta respuesta por ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2894/83). El consenso en SO es etiquetar con la etiqueta del lenguaje y, si es necesario, con la específica de la versión. Que la gente nueva no lo esté siguiendo no quiere decir que debamos cambiar el consenso. Lo que habría que hacer es reetiquetar cuando nos lo encontramos.

Comment: La etiquetas deberían servir para facilitar la búsqueda y, hoy en día, la etiqueta [python-3.x] no añade ninguna información. De acuerdo en reetiquetar. Pero ya me dirás qué pregunta de python es tan específica como para que lleve la etiqueta [python-3.x]. Si tengo que reetiquetar alguna pregunta, sería para quitar esta etiqueta y dejar sólo [python].

Comment: @ChemaCortes absolutamente de acuerdo en lo de _La etiquetas deberían servir para facilitar la búsqueda_. De ahí que valga la pena usar [tag:poo], [tag:diccionarios], [tag:lista] y las de frameworks como [tag:django] y demás. Una pregunta puede bien usar [tag:python-3.x] si pregunta por algo específico de Python 3, como type hints u otros. Lo que yo tiendo a hacer es precisamente esto que mencionas: quitar [tag:python-3.x] para poner [tag:python]. Pensemos en cómo querremos buscar cuando aparezca Python 4 y haya cosas no compatibles con Python 3.

Comment: Es que aunque pregunten por _typehints_, la etiqueta [python-3.x] no aporta ninguna información, ya que aparecen a partir de la versión 3.5. Precisamente, alguien que empieza debería considerar los _typehints_ como parte de lenguaje python, sin referencia a versión específica. Cuando llegue python 4, supongo que será dentro de 10 años y seguiremos aún discutiendo si fusionar o no las etiquetas python.

Comment: @ChemaCortes recomiendo la lectura de la [info wiki de python en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info), allí se ve el fruto de bastante discusión y consecución de consenso tras muchos años de trabajo.

Comment: La tengo bastante leída, pero sigo sin entender a qué se refiere con _"only add this one if your question is version-specific"_. ¿Acaso hay que etiquetar con [python-3.x] todo lo que sea incompatible con [python-2.x]?

Comment: @ChemaCortes no, yo no lo entiendo así, sino que se añada [python-X] cuando se habla de funcionalidades incorporadas en ese Python X determinado y que, por tanto, el código debe estar en ese Python para que funcione. También relevante que sea algo que otras versiones no tengan. Por ejemplo, si estamos hablando de iterar un diccionario con `iteritems()`, pues deberá ser Python 2. Y sí, coincido en que Python 3 es prácticamente el código por defecto.